# How many $01$ or $10$ substrings are there, on average, in a random $n$-bit string containing $k$ ones.

Tags: combinatorics, average, combinatorial-proofs

For example, if $n = 4$ and $k = 2$, then we have ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ strings:

$$
1100 \rightarrow 1\\
0011 \rightarrow 1\\
1001 \rightarrow 2\\
0110 \rightarrow 2\\
1010 \rightarrow 3\\
0101 \rightarrow 3
$$

The number $N$ of $01$ or $10$ substrings is shown beside each string. In this case, the *average* number is

$$\bar{N}(4,2) = \frac{12}{6}$$

So, what's the general formula for $\bar{N}(n,k)$, the average number of $01$ or $10$ substrings in a random $n$-bit string containing $k$ ones?

Comment: Hi. Your question should appear in the body of the post (not just the title).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese fixed, thanks

Comment: Let $A_b(n,k)$ be the number of $10$'s or $01$'s among words of length $n$ with $k$ 1's, eg $A_{00}(n,k)$ is counts words ending in $00$.  Now you should be able to get recurrences for the four $A_b$ if you look through all the possibilities of appending $0$s or $1$s to strings and how it changes the statistic you want to find.

Comment: This is a classic technique. For each position where a “01” can occur, calculate the probability that a “01” actually does occur there. The sum of these probabilities will be the expected number of “01”s. This is by linearity of expectation.

Comment: @MarkSaving You're right, that's much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability of $01$ or $10$ appearing in each individual two-bit window of the $n$-bit string is the probability of drawing one $0$ and one $1$ from a bag of $k$ ones and $n-k$ zeros, given by the hypergeometric distribution:
$$\frac{\binom k1\binom{n-k}1}{\binom n2}=\frac{2k(n-k)}{n(n-1)}$$
There are $n-1$ such two-bit windows, so linearity of expectation gives $\overline N(n,k)$ as $n-1$ times the previous probability or $\frac{2k(n-k)}n$.

Comment: That is correct! Recognizing that it's a hypergeometric distribution really simplifies the problem. Since posting the question, the best I could do was a counting argument looking at the number of "01" or "10" pairs among all the words, at any of the $n-1$ spaces in between. That gave me $\overline N(n,k) = (n - 1) \times 2{n - 2 \choose k - 1}/{n \choose k} = 2k{n - 1 \choose k}/{n \choose k}$, with the factor of $2$ accounting for either "01" or "10". This reduces to the answer you gave in one line, but takes a lot more work. Thank you for the more elegant solution!